# Visual Studio 2010 Conversion issue not recognizing prefix 'asp'

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, .net-4.0, prefix

I just converted a project from Visual Studio 2008 to 2010 and all of my asp controls have a warning stating..

`Unrecognized tag prefix or device filter 'asp'.`

It also is not showing any intellisense, anyone else experiencing similar issues? Is it possible my conversion did not go through correctly?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I too was having this issue, I resolved it by deleting the C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\VisualStudio\10.0 folder

Comment: I just continued to work with the project unconverted. When I get a chance I will attempt your suggestion. However, doesn't this do it for all projects? I am getting intellisense on other projects just not this specific one.

Comment: Marked as correct beause it was the only answer and I no longer have access to the machine in the question.